# How to calculate the characteristic Function with a Turning-Machine?

Tags: computer-science

I have the following question that I need to answer  :

> Proof that the set $P=\{w \in \{0,1\}^{*}|w \ is \ divisible \ by \ 2\}$ is decidable. Construct a Turing-Machine which calculates the characteristic Function of $P$.

It is very obvious to me how to construct the Turning Machine. I construct a loop which goes to the end and if there is a one it is not divisible and if it is a zero then it is. But the problem now is how to output my answer. Do I simply delete every number on the tape and write then a zero or a one. Or do I define a state and say if it ends in $q_4$ it is even and if it is in $q_5$ it is odd?

Comment: Turning machine?

Comment: Not exactly clear what $w$ is, I guess a binary string from which we want to know whether it represents an even number. Just determine the last digit of this string and verify whether it is $0$.

Comment: Yes but how do I output wether it is 0 or not?

Comment: Just write the digit behind the input with one space between.

Comment: OK ty this is what I wanted to know